Thoughts and analogy in cognition
continuing Question about word (relationship between language and thought)
Without concepts there can be no thought, and without analogies there can be no concepts. —Hofstadter and Sander
My question is if thought comes before words , how do you create an analogy(which turns into concepts which turns into thoughts) without words  ?

Many thoughts are visual by their sensibility or intelligibility and there's a picture theory of semantics of language which is invented to describe these visuals and people can certainly communicate solely by drawing pictures, and by etymological evolution some of the usual communicated pictures by the original humans were morphed to symbol like languages...

@DoubleKnot yes then Hofstadter is wrong

The great apes, and indeed most animals, appear to be achieving cognition with little or no language. Language is a remarkably efficient tool for structuring and communicating ideas, especially abstract ideas, but it isn't the only tool. (Notes that I'm saying cognition, not sentience, I don't want to get into arguments over whether that is a difference in kind or just a difference in degree.)

@quanity - You cannot simply say that -- because of DoubleKnots's statements - "then Hofstadter is wrong". According to Hofstadter, analogy making is a core process in thought and perception. As such it's pre-verbal. Verbal analogies are just the tip of the iceberg. The core phenomenon is "seeing (an) x as (a) y".

@mudskipper u mean analogy is independent of words?

Yes. Verbal expressions of analogy don't seem as fundamental as seeing-as. See also my answer below.

reopen it guys ..

I think an example from the animal kingdom can be enlightening.
Years ago, Dutch-American primatologist Frans de Waal did an experiment with two capuchin monkeys who would perform a task and then get a reward. Monkey one does her task and gets a piece of cucumber. She is happy and eats the piece of cucumber. Then monkey two does her task, visible to monkey one, and gets a grape. A grape  is much better than a piece of cucumber. Then it's monkey one's turn again and she does her task. Again she gets a piece of cucumber. This time she throws a tantrum. She wants the grape! You can watch the video here. It's hilarious.
Since capuchin monkeys cannot speak and have no words, this behaviour must have its origin in conceptual thinking and, arguably, analogies. Now, I am not a primatologist or an ethologist myself, and we should take care not to anthropomorphise, but it seems quite obvious that the first monkey compares herself to the other monkey, draws an analogy, and perceives an injustice, namely an unfair reward for the same task.
As to how this works? According neuroscience research, we use the prefrontal cortex, particularly the ventromedial prefrontal cortex, for running mental simulations. We do this when we are imagining future scenarios and predicting potential outcomes. This allows us and capuchin monkeys, to play out possible events in our minds before taking action.
The video is also food for thought for those who think that only humans have moral behaviour...

+1 Great summary. I once met De Waal at a lecture + book signing event. He was pretty grumpy and unfriendly to my wife, who asked him to sign her copy to "To whom it may concern". He replied in an irritated voice "Now, why would I do so?!" and refused to do so. I imagine that he was imagining us as wanting to sell his book for a higher price to someone on eBay or so.  If so, then he was selling himself too cheap, by making those assumptions and being unfriendly, I'd say now :)

If you find that experiment interesting then you may want to further investigate theories of mirror neurons in apes and the shared manifold hypothesis https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/14504450/ wherein we recognize the actions of others using neural structures that generate perceptions of self interacting with the external social and natural world. Sigmund Freud argued for efforts to govern action in the world wherein the infantile ego strives to imitate (ape) one or more superior ego(s) in the form of external authority figures. This incorporates memories of ego-superego interactions into ego.

@mudskipper Great story! ...I imagine that he was imagening... Your prefrontal cortex trying to out-maneuver his prefrontal cortex. Ha ha.

@SystemTheory I had heard of mirror neurons but this was a very interesting abstract. and it would be a great answer too. Would need some rewording though... Thank you.

In the past I found published papers by Vittorio Gillese by google search. Search results now may be inferior. Often, I type in the name of the author with keyword [pdf] and known title of papers, then use further keywords that pop-up in results to search for more possible published papers. My problem with psychotherapy models is that the therapy community fails to recognize the therapist as playing the superego role in social reenactments of ego-superego memories. The suffering patient pays money to the therapist which is a reenactment element. A suffering child 'pays' during socialization.

An analogy is a relation. Just as we can perceive or imagine 'higher' or 'lower' (physical relations) before the words 'higher' or 'lower' come to mind, we can perceive or imagine 'similar to' (analogical relations) before we formulate the analogy as a phrase. Just think of the typical experience of irony (a humorous analogy): we notice something odd, we smirk for a moment while we figure out exactly what's odd about it, and only then do the words for it come.

According to Hofstadter, analogy making is a core process of all thought and perception. As such this is pre-verbal. It's a form of perception seeing (an) X as (a) Y, seeing this as like that. This focuses on perception as perception of similarity/difference (rather than perception as perception of objects, identities). When we want to know how we can recognize, for instance, a chair, we focus on what it may be that enables us to perceive that thing, or those things, as belonging to some class of things (chairs). (Even framing it like that is already misleading. We don't start from some given 'class of chairs'. Plus, we cannot actually point to any determinate 'concept of chair' under which we supposedly would be 'subsuming' the things we're pointing at. So, we're asking: How or why do we perceive all those things as "the same"? How do we come by a fuzzy and extremely fluid, yet usable, commucationable -- is that a word? -- concept of a chair?) Since we don't have any introspective data about how this happens, we need to look for other means to explain how we do this.
Example (coming from Hofstadter). Talk to a 3- or 4-year old. Point with your index finger to your nose, and ask the child: "Do this!" (Now, "this" is really ambiguous here. It clearly has no fixed linguistic meaning, as will become clear.) What will the child do? It sees you pointing at your nose. Some young children may now simply also point at your nose, while somewhat older children may laugh and point at their own nose. In both cases, the child interpreted your words, giving its own meaning to "this", by imitating your gesture. In both cases the child made a (valid) analogy -- pre-verbally, non-verbally -- by making its gesture -- either pointing to its own nose, or to yours. What are the processes underlying this - that's still an open question in cognitive science, ML and neurology.

+1 I'd also add cognitive neuroscience. The ontology helps to reduce psychology to neurology and is arguably the analog of computer engineering. The basic ontological primitives of psychology like attention, phonic production, executive function are mapped out on the anatomy they arise  from or supervene on.

Analogies can form without words, as they often start from mental images, sensory experiences, or emotions. These non-verbal connections allow us to make comparisons before language is involved. Words then help refine and articulate the analogy, but the core of the analogy can exist in the mind before it’s expressed verbally.
